# how to use Juliar programming language on lighttpd?

Tags: server, lighttpd

I have been working with this new language for a while and now I want to use juliar on Lighttpd there are no guides for that. However  that there is a guide for Apache and Nginx. How do I configure my server for Lighttpd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Juliar doesn't officially support lighttpd.
However, you can do the following:

Open your lighttpd.conf file and add the following:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_fastcgi",
)

fastcgi.server += ( ".ju" => 
    ((
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => "9000",
        "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
    ))
)

index-file.names=("index.ju","index.html")
```

Then just use "linuxspawn.sh" script and reload your lighttpd server.